# Type Error on Plotly for 3D scatter from pandas database

Tags: python, plotly

I am getting an error when I try to plot my data from a pandas dataframe on the new updated version of plotly, plotly 4.0. The examples from the [website](https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/) work perfectly when I run them but not when I tried to base the data on a dataframe I created. I am working in a Jupyter Notebook environment and I have also tried the Plot with go.Scatter3d approach and got the same error.

my dataframe `df` loks like this if I print it using `print(df)`

```
     X    Y   Z
0    0   -5   0
1    5    0   0
2   10    5   0
3   15   10   0
4    0   -5   5
5    5    0   5
6   10    5   5
7   15   10   5
8    0   -5  10
9    5    0  10
10  10    5  10
11  15   10  10
12   0   -5  15
13   5    0  15
14  10    5  15
15  15   10  15
16   0  -10   0
17   5   -5   0
18  10    0   0
19  15    5   0
20   0  -10   5
21   5   -5   5
22  10    0   5
23  15    5   5
24   0  -10  10
25   5   -5  10
26  10    0  10
27  15    5  10
28   0  -10  15
29   5   -5  15
30  10    0  15
31  15    5  15
32   0  -15   0
33   5  -10   0
34  10   -5   0
35  15    0   0
36   0  -15   5
37   5  -10   5
38  10   -5   5
39  15    0   5
40   0  -15  10
41   5  -10  10
42  10   -5  10
43  15    0  10
44   0  -15  15
45   5  -10  15
46  10   -5  15
47  15    0  15
```

Below is my method for plotting `df`,

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z')
fig.show()
```

I get a really long error message ending in,

```
TypeError: Object of type Zero is not JSON serializable
```

I have searched for a fix to this issue and could not find one, I would greatly appreciate any help.

The whole error message below,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-41b61849b7ea> in <module>
      2 
      3 fig = px.scatter_3d(data_frame = df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z')
----> 4 fig.show()

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2652         import plotly.io as pio
   2653 
-> 2654         return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2655 
   2656     def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_renderers.py in show(fig, renderer, validate, **kwargs)
    372 
    373     # Mimetype renderers
--> 374     bundle = renderers._build_mime_bundle(fig_dict, renderers_string=renderer, **kwargs)
    375     if bundle:
    376         if not ipython_display:

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_renderers.py in _build_mime_bundle(self, fig_dict, renderers_string, **kwargs)
    292                         setattr(renderer, k, v)
    293 
--> 294                 bundle.update(renderer.to_mimebundle(fig_dict))
    295 
    296         return bundle

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_base_renderers.py in to_mimebundle(self, fig_dict)
     92 
     93         json_compatible_fig_dict = json.loads(
---> 94             to_json(fig_dict, validate=False, remove_uids=False)
     95         )
     96 

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_json.py in to_json(fig, validate, pretty, remove_uids)
     54         opts["separators"] = (",", ":")
     55 
---> 56     return json.dumps(fig_dict, cls=PlotlyJSONEncoder, **opts)
     57 
     58 

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\utils.py in encode(self, o)
     42 
     43         # this will raise errors in a normal-expected way
---> 44         encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
     45 
     46         # now:

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\utils.py in default(self, obj)
    111             except NotEncodable:
    112                 pass
--> 113         return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
    114 
    115     @staticmethod

c:\users\nihal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type Zero is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please don't do screenshots for text... paste the text of your code and error message here so it is readable...

Comment: @Hoog Thank you, I have applied your suggestion

Comment: I am not very familiar with `plotly` but perhaps the dataframe input is not a positional input.  The following line might work to plot based on a few other examples I have seen: `fig = px.scatter_3d(data_frame = df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z')`

Comment: @Hoog Tried it and no luck, I will add the rest of the error message in case that helps.

Comment: Where does `df` come from? is it a Pandas object or something else?

Comment: ```df``` is a pandas dataframe I had initiated like ```df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the numbers in my dataframe were in some format that plotly could not interpret. I was able to fix this issue by converting all my entries to floats. Thank you for all the responses.